# How do I add specific css for my modal on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a modal login form that was made on a previews project, on html and css. Now I am doing another project but with bootstrap, I want to implement it there. But I am not being able to do so.

Here is my modals html(inside index.html):

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#">
        <h1>MMT University</h1>
        <span>Se registre para começar</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
        <button name="submit">Registrar</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
        <h1>Acessar</h1>
        
        <span>Acesse a MMT University</span>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
        <a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
        <button>Acessar</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
          <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
          <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
          <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
          <h1>MMT University!</h1>
          <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
          <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is it's css (That I added next to the css from bootstrap):

```
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
    0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}
.close {
  /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close button on hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background:  #05031b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #05031b, #05031b);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Now this css is not being displayed for some reason. Anyone got any idea??

This is how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

And how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: In your modal html, I can't see any relevant css for your modal? Where is your modal html  position in your site html? Is it inside the `.wrapper`? Not that it matters as I can't see any styles here that would hit your modal items.

Comment: Ok I reuploaded the modal css. I may add, whenever I add those css files to my style.css, the navbar, hero section and modal, break down.

Comment: Your screenshot and modal code has 4 main content sections, but your 'how it should look' screenshot only has 2?

Answer (score 0):

There was no bootstrap classes in your modal html. Normally if you are using bootstrap you utilise their classes and customise them so they work globally to theme your site elements consistently.

As mentioned in comments you have 4 core layout elements in your modal html, so I've hidden the last element with class `.overlay-container` as I don't know how you want to handle them visually.

The first 2 `.form-container` elements i've set to 50% width using flex and reset `flex-direction` to `initial` so form containers abide by the 50% set width.

Your modal html `.form-container` elements for `.sign-up-container` and `.sign-in-container` were in the wrong order to achieve your 'supposed to look like' screenshot. You can either re-arrange your html or use css flex `order` to arrange them. Which i've used in demo below.

I've also utilised bootstraps `.form-group` class by wrapping your inputs with a div with this class. And I also added bootstraps `.form-control` classes to your inputs.

See CSS below on how to target elements in your modal and style them to your liking.

```css
#myModal .modal-content {
  flex-direction: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#myModal .form-container {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#myModal .sign-up-container {
  order: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#myModal .sign-in-container {
  order: 0;
}

#myModal .overlay-container {
  display: none;
```

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Login Modal
</button>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#" class="w-100">
          <h4 class="mb-3">MMT University</h4>
          <p>Se registre para começar</p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
          <h4 class="mb-3">Acessar</h4>
          <p>Acesse a MMT University</p>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
          </div>
          <p><a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a></p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Acessar</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
            <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
            <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
            <h1>MMT University!</h1>
            <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Update to your comments

I guess you are trying to emulate a bootstrap modal animation effect using css, and with out actually using bootstrap. If you are not using bootstrap theres probably not much point importing it now at the stage you are at.

I made a very rough example below on how you can use css transition to animate your modal by adding an `open` class to your modal div. With out using bootstrap. See demo below.

Not sure if this is what you are after. Hope it gets you on the right track.

```js
// any modal button
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(e) {
  
  // get the modal target
  let target = $(this).data('target');

  // if target has open class
  if($(target).hasClass('open')) {
  
   // remove open class
   $(target).removeClass('open');
  
  } else {
  
   // add open class
   $(target).addClass('open');
   
  }  

});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.modal.open {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
}

#myModal .modal-content {
  flex-direction: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

#myModal .form-container {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#myModal .sign-up-container {
  order: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#myModal .sign-in-container {
  order: 0;
}

#myModal .overlay-container {
  display: none;
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Login Modal
</button>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    
    <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
        <form action="#">
          <h4>Acessar</h4>
          <p>Acesse a MMT University</p>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
          <p><a href="#">Esqueceu a senha?</a></p>
          <button type="submit">Acessar</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
        <form action="#" class="w-100">
          <h4>MMT University</h4>
          <p>Se registre para começar</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" />
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Repita a sua senha" />
          <br/>
          <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="overlay-container">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
            <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
            <p>Para continuar aprendendo, acesse a sua conta!</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
            <h1>MMT University!</h1>
            <p>Se registre para entrar na melhor universidade trading do mundo.</p>
            <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Registre-se</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey man. Thank you so much for your answer. My modal is now working and the css is working properly. If you could just help me out with one thing.
 My other modal has an animation, that I will show on the next comment. Can I just add the normal html and css code for it? (How I added in the other one, or will that be incompatible due to having to do it with the bootstrap classes?)

Comment: https://universitymmt.com/welcome.php Please click the top right button and play with that modal, it has that animation. How do I change that to bootstrap?

Comment: Are you actually using bootstrap 4 on this site?

Comment: I am using html/css on the website I sent you. That website is only using html and css (not bootstrap). I am asking if there is a way to make the same animations but on this one, with bootstrap. Adding them to this modal you helped me make?

Comment: You mean the opening animation? Like in my demo? When I click your modal, it just instantly appears and looks quite nice. If you not using bootstrap theres probably not much importing it at the stage you are at. I'm not quite sure what you are after, you after jquery script to animate you modal appearing.

Comment: Oh, like if you click the button on the right, it has a slide animation that displays the register page. Once the register page is open on the right, you get a button on the left to go to the login page

Comment: Could you please help me out? It is supposed to have those side "panels"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224112/discussion-between-joshmoto-and-tomas-mota).